# Fixed element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed

How do people program these toolbars and menus so that once you scroll down a certain amount on the page it'll become a fixed element?  Is there a guide/tutorial anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin such as [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) to achieve [that effect](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/).